# Can I use crawled from Node.js in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, web-crawler

I'm new to javaScript and trying to crawl a website with node.js. I could check the data in console log, but want to use the data in another javaScript file. How can I fetch the data?

The problem is I've never used node.js. I do javaScript so I know how to write the code, but I don't know how the back-end or server works.

I've tried to open it in my local host but the node method (e.g., require()) didn't work. I found out it's because node doesn't work in browser.(See? very new to js)

Should I use bundler or something?

The steps I thought were,

- somehow send the data as json
- somehow fetch the json data and render

Here is the crawling code file.

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const log = console.log;

const getHtml = async () => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(URL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

getHtml()
  .then(html => {
    let ulList = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
    const $bodyList = $("div.info-timetable ul").children("li");


    $bodyList.each(function(i, elem) {
      ulList[i] = {
          screen: $(this).find('a').attr('data-screenname'),
          time: $(this).find('a').attr('data-playstarttime')  
        };
    });

    const data = ulList.filter(n => n.time);
    return data;
  })
  .then(res => log(res));
```

Could you please explain what steps should I take?

Also, it would be great if I can get understood WHY the steps are needed.

Thanks alot!

Comment: the crawling code file is there, so you are using a node server, right? You just need to export the data to the other file where you need it. Or better yet just export the function which crawls and returns the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try writing your data to a JSON file and proceed, that's one way, then you can use the data as an object in any js file

```
const appendFile = (file, contents) =>
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
fs.appendFile(
  file,
  contents,
  'utf8',
  err => (err ? reject(err) : resolve()),
);
 });

getHtml()
 .then(html => {
let ulList = [];
const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
const $bodyList = $("div.info-timetable ul").children("li");


$bodyList.each(function(i, elem) {
  ulList[i] = {
      screen: $(this).find('a').attr('data-screenname'),
      time: $(this).find('a').attr('data-playstarttime')  
    };
});

const data = ulList.filter(n => n.time);
return data;
})
.then(res => {
   return appendFile('./data.json',res.toString())
}))
.then(done => {log('updated data json')});
```